# How to compensate for space left by a relatively positioned element? (Without making a mess)

Tags: html, css, layout, position, css-position

I have these three elements:

[image]

Now, my layout mandates that element `.b` (by the way, if it's important, they're all html `<section>`s) is somewhat superimposed on element `.a`. So I decide to apply `position: relative` to it, then nudge it up using `top: -50px`.

What happens is this:

[image]

I successfully superimposed the two top elements, but now I created an unnecessary 50px space between `.b` and `.c`. (They were supposed to be glued together.)

My first guess was to apply an equivalent `margin-bottom: -50px`, but this didn't work, for some reason I'm also not aware.

Eventually I resolved it in a roundabout way by making `.b` a child of `.a`. This caused `.a` to overflow above `.c`, but then I applied a magic number amount of `margin-bottom` to it in order to push `.c` back down.

Of course, I'm not happy with this solution, so I'm asking here.

What would say is the best way to resolve this?

By **best way** I mean I want to avoid, if possible:

- the creation of additional nonsemantic markup
- applying the same `top: -50px` rule to all subsequent elements on the page
- using any kind of magic number on my CSS.

I just want to learn the best practice when dealing with this, because I assume it's going be a problem I will be encountering more times in the future.

Comment: just remove the `position: relative` and use `margin-top: -50px` instead and it'll work :)

Comment: What. Was I. Thinking. (Thanks!)

Answer (score 2):

So, several ways to accomplish this.

My suggestion would be to utilize `margin-top` on the element you want to overflow. Everything else will render properly and only one item needs to be positioned properly.

Visual Representation:

[image]

HTML

```
<div id="one">Item 1</div>
<div id="two">Item 2</div>
<div id="three">Item 3</div>
```

CSS

```
#one, #two, #three {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#one {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #ABC;
}
#two {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #CBA;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
#three {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #BBB;
}
```

Example provided here:

http://jsfiddle.net/dp83o0vt/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting

```
top: -50px;
```

simply set

```
margin-top: -50px;
```

This way your `.c` still sticks to `.b`, and you don't have to mess with anything else.

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gyrgfqdx/

Comment: Thanks! This is so simple, I'm a little embarrassed. Can't explain how or why it didn't occur me to do it this way instead of uselessly positioning...